# Textscan until end of line

Tags: matlab, format-specifiers, textscan

I'm trying to textscan a file and read a single line until the end of it, undependently of the number of elements in that line.

My file is a **.txt** file formatted like this :

```
602,598,302,456,1023,523,....
293,291,566,331,987,56,....
589,202,429,2911,294,567,...
```

And so on. I have the number of the line, and all lines have the same number of elements, but it can vary from one file to another.

I wrote something like:

```
fid = fopen('somefile.txt');
C = textscan(fid, formatSpec,'HeaderLines',Row-1);
TheLine = C{1};
fclose(fid);

X = numel(TheLine);
plot(1:X,TheLine);
```

I really don't know what to type in the `formatSpec` field. I've tried a few things in the way of `%[^\n]` but I didn't get much sucess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
C = textscan(fid, '%d,','HeaderLines',Row-1);
```

Row will specify the row of data that you want to extract from the text file.

Comment: Sweet! It works fine! Can you explain fast how this works? I haven't seen anything of the likes online...

Comment: @Marc-olivierLessard Well let's suppose that you know there are 6 elements in that particular row, you would usually do - `C = textscan(fid, '%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,','HeaderLines',Row-1)`. Now if you don't know the number of elements, but you know that the elements are of consistent format then you would mention only one `%d,` and MATLAB would internally replicate it. This is a big of a guestimate at this point though backed up by some doc search and code runs.